# bs4 tag.children[2] gives 'listiterator object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code (Python 2.7, bs4) which works:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.zidisha.org/microfinance/loan/youmpi/1434.html").read())
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
tag = soup.find(text=re.compile("On-Time Repayments:")).find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td")

print type(tag)
for child in tag.children:
print repr(child)

#Output:
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
u'\n'
u'modified by Julia to add number of months repayments were due 15-10-2013'
u'\n\n80% (10)\n\n'
```

I want to get the third element in the tag -- "80% (10)" -- (stripping and converting from unicode is no problem), but when I try and define:
myVar = tag.children[2], I get the following error:
'listiterator object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I put in a hack fix by using:
myVar = tag.next_element.next_element.next_element.strip(), but feel like my IDE is judging me.

I thought anything I could iterate through with a list comprehension I could grab a particular element in with an index, but obviously not. What's the best way to get the third (or theoretically 20th) element of a tag without chaining .next_element methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.contents` instead of `.children` if you want to access the chilldren as list.

See [.contents and .children](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Indeed .contents[2] worked perfectly. And thanks for the doc link, I obviously didn't read that section carefully enough before.